How to check if an array contains elements or not
Have to check if the array contains elements or not. if so then should add sourceKey element the array. Always key.sourceKey element should be passed in partySales.item array only if item array have other elements. if the item array is empty then don't send partySales object at all in the output json
Input
{
  "accountType": "MASTER",
  "AccountInfo": {
    "id": "1234",
    "mcaCountry": "CA",
    "accountRegion": "EMEA",
    "marketRegion": "EMEA"
  }
}

SPECS:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "accountType": {
        "MASTER": {
          "@2,AccountInfo.id": "key",
          "#Master": "key"
        },
        "OPERATIONAL": {
          "@2,AccountInfo.id": "key",
          "#~": "key"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "key": "=join(~,@(1,&))",
      "partySalesKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'')"
    }
  },

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "AccountInfo": {
        "accountRegion": {
          "AMER": {
            "#0001": "PartySales.item[#2].IbxRegionCd.RegionCd",
            "#AMER": "PartySales.item[#2].IbxRegionCd.RegionDesc"
          },
          "APAC": {
            "#0002": "PartySales.item[#2].IbxRegionCd.RegionCd",
            "#APAC": "PartySales.item[#2].IbxRegionCd.RegionDesc"
          },
          "EMEA": {
            "#0003": "PartySales.item[#2].IbxRegionCd.RegionCd",
            "#EMEA": "PartySales.item[#2].IbxRegionCd.RegionDesc"
          }
        },
        "mcaCountry": {
          "@1,mcaCountry": [
            "PartySales.item[#1].McaCntryCd.cntryCd",
            "PartySales.item[#1].McaCntryCd.cntryDesc"
          ]
        },
        "marketRegion": {
          "AMER": {
            "@1,marketRegion": "PartySales.item[#2].RegionCd.RegionDesc",
            "#0001": "PartySales.item[#2].RegionCd.RegionCd"
          },
          "APAC": {
            "@1,marketRegion": "PartySales.item[#2].RegionCd.RegionDesc",
            "#0002": "PartySales.item[#2].RegionCd.RegionCd"
          },
          "EMEA": {
            "@2,marketRegion": "PartySales.item[#2].RegionCd.RegionDesc",
            "#0003": "PartySales.item[#2].RegionCd.RegionCd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "key": "key.sourceKey",
      "partySalesKey": "PartySales.item[#2].key.sourceKey"
    }
  }

]


Expected: If item array is not empty
{
  "PartySales": {
    "item": [
      {
        "IbxRegionCd": {
          "RegionCd": "0003",
          "RegionDesc": "EMEA"
        },
        "McaCntryCd": {
          "cntryCd": "CA",
          "cntryDesc": "CA"
        },
        "RegionCd": {
          "RegionDesc": "EMEA",
          "RegionCd": "0003"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": {
          "sourceKey": "1234~Master"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

If item array is empty then expected response:
{}

But initially there's no such an array called item

yes, there's no such an array called item
